# Oracle Apex - Send Email from a list

Tags: oracle, email, oracle-apex

I have a table with a list of several different emails and Items. I'm trying to send out an email (whenever a button is pressed) to all of those emails with their Items, e.g.:

[image: table example]

An email like this should be send when the button is pressed:

"Dear abc@mail.com, your cart is ready with item 1 and item 2."

I know how to send emails using Apex Items but I'm lost on how to do it with information inside a table.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be one option: create a procedure which runs when button is pressed; it reads table contents and "aggregates" list of items into message text.

As you already know how to send mail, I hope this is enough for you to make it work.

```
SQL> with test (user_email, item) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'abc@mail.com', 'item 1' from dual union all
  4     select 'abc@mail.com', 'item 2' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select '123@mail.com', 'item 1' from dual union all
  7     select '123@mail.com', 'item 2' from dual union all
  8     select '123@mail.com', 'item 3' from dual
  9    )
 10  -- code you might be interested in
 11  select user_email,
 12    'Dear ' || user_email ||', your cart is ready with ' ||
 13    listagg(item, ', ') within group (order by item) as message_text
 14  from test
 15  group by user_email
 16  /

USER_EMAIL   MESSAGE_TEXT
------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
123@mail.com Dear 123@mail.com, your cart is ready with item 1, item 2, item 3
abc@mail.com Dear abc@mail.com, your cart is ready with item 1, item 2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps. Question please, I'm trying to compile all the emails using a listagg (comma separated) in a Varchar2 variable. Issue is, apex_mail.send doesn't seem to like using a Varchar2 on the ''p_to'' part. Do you know how can I use a variable on that specific ''p_to'' field?

Comment: You're welcome. But, why would you "aggregate" all e-mail addresses? Looks as if you'd then send the same message to all of them? That would be wrong, wouldn't it? I presume you'd rather send mails one-by-one, to only one recipient (with their message text) at a time. How? In a loop.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!